# rendering html with math jax

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

I want to render a string which has both html codes and mathjax tex code and show on my web page using angular js

I have made a directive but its only rendering the tex codes and not the html 
ie My string has

`$\int x^2dx = 2x + C$`


My directive code

```
app.directive("mathjaxBind", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs",
                    function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                        $scope.$watch($attrs.mathjaxBind, function(texExpression) {
                            $element.html(texExpression);
                            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, $element[0]]);
                        });
                    }]
            };
        });
```